# Почему в этом решении используется остаток для деления?

Tags: python

Есть такая задача и есть ее, на мой взгляд, очень хорошее решение.
Сама задача:

> N человек, пронумерованных числами от 1 до N, стоят в кругу. Они начинают играть в считалку на выбывание, где каждый K-й по счёту человек выбывает из круга, после чего счёт продолжается со следующего за ним человека. На вход подаётся количество человек N и номер K. Напишите программу, которая выводит число от 1 до N — это номер человека, который останется в кругу последним.

Решение:

```
number = int(input('Какое число в считалке? '))
print('Значит, выбывает каждый', number, 'человек.')
mens_list = list(range(1, num + 1))
out = 0

for _ in range(num - 1):
   print('Текущий круг людей', mens_list)
   start_count = out % len(mens_list)
   out = (start_count + number - 1) % len(mens_list)
   print('Начало счёта с номера', mens_list[start_count])
   print('Выбывает человек под номером', mens_list[out])
   mens_list.remove(mens_list[out])
   print()
print('Остался человек под номером', mens_list)
```

Суть вопроса:
*Как начинающему понять, что для решения задачи подошла бы формула  out = (start_count + number - 1) % len(mens_list) с остатком от деления?*

**Можете объяснить логику размышлений именно для написания такой формулы, а не для кода?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На часах было 12:45, затем затем 46 минут, затем час и 7 минут. Сколько минут на часах?

```
((12 * 60 + 45) + 46 + (1 * 60 + 7)) % 60
```

тут тот же принцип

поскольку движение по кругу, используем модулярную арифметику

т.е. сначала вычисляется некоторая абсолютная позиция человека как `start_count + number - 1`, а затем через определения модуля по кол-ву человек (`len(mens_list)`) ее относительная позиция в круге

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и что потратили время! Очень полезно и понятно!

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что вы понимаете под "как понять". Как догадаться, что здесь пригодится остаток? Очень просто - накопить опыт.

Почему используется остаток: потому что в данном случае нас не интересует какое количество полных кругов пройдет считалка.

Если в круге N человек и выбывает каждый k-ый, то номер этого выбывшего Nv и будет как раз остаток от деления N на k: N = x*k + Nv, где x - количество полных кругов и оно нас совершенно не интересует, сколько бы их ни было, на результат это не влияет.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как нагуглить, в каких случаях используется остаток от деления? Я знаю только два условия - нахождение четного и нечетного чисел и последнего числа. Был бы признателен, если бы подсказали, как нагуглить полный список применения остатка от деления. Спасибо!

Comment: нет такого списка и не может быть. Это как спросить список применений теоремы Пифагора. или таблицы умножения.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо! Знаний по математике мне очень не хватает (